# Connect to On-premise ADFS (https) authenticated site using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

How can we connect to an On-premise ADFS (https) authenticated site using CSOM?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/09/09/setup-sharepoint-online-on-premises-single-sign-on-sso/

Comment: @Supermode The blog you suggested is to setup SSO between on-premise and online envs. I am looking to setup the clientcontext in an on-premise env using adfs.